# Button search or filter

Tags: javascript, html

I have textbox and button here. But when I'm searching the data, data not available.

> HTML

```
     <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Item Name"/>
     <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="button" value="Search"/>
```

> JavaScript

```
 $('#btnSearch').click(function(e){
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var field = 'itemName';
        var operator = 'contains';
        var value = this.value;
        grid.dataSource.filter({
          field: field,
          operator: operator,
          value: value
        });
      });
```

Comment: what you are getting in this.value?

Comment: Various of item name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you..!

```js
$('.searchBtn').click(function() {
  var title = $('#title').val(); //value from search input box
  $('.pubTitle').each(function() { //searches each container
    var str = $(this).text(); //finds just the title text
    if (str.indexOf(title) > -1) { //compares search text to title text
      $(this).show(); // if the entry is found show the container
    } else {
      $(this).hide(); // if not found, hide it.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: same answer as mine :)

Comment: @Mowgli ha ha yeah!! little diff <3

Comment: ha ha yu too dude!

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8G2Q) you can find full example of search and ready design using bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>The columns titles are merged with the filters inputs thanks to the placeholders attributes</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Inspired by this <a href="http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-tables-with-filter">snippet</a></p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Users</h3>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> Filter</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters">
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" disabled></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Larry</td>
                        <td>the Bird</td>
                        <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.filterable {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filterable .btn-filter').click(function(){
        var $panel = $(this).parents('.filterable'),
        $filters = $panel.find('.filters input'),
        $tbody = $panel.find('.table tbody');
        if ($filters.prop('disabled') == true) {
            $filters.prop('disabled', false);
            $filters.first().focus();
        } else {
            $filters.val('').prop('disabled', true);
            $tbody.find('.no-result').remove();
            $tbody.find('tr').show();
        }
    });

    $('.filterable .filters input').keyup(function(e){
        /* Ignore tab key */
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == '9') return;
        /* Useful DOM data and selectors */
        var $input = $(this),
        inputContent = $input.val().toLowerCase(),
        $panel = $input.parents('.filterable'),
        column = $panel.find('.filters th').index($input.parents('th')),
        $table = $panel.find('.table'),
        $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
        /* Dirtiest filter function ever ;) */
        var $filteredRows = $rows.filter(function(){
            var value = $(this).find('td').eq(column).text().toLowerCase();
            return value.indexOf(inputContent) === -1;
        });
        /* Clean previous no-result if exist */
        $table.find('tbody .no-result').remove();
        /* Show all rows, hide filtered ones (never do that outside of a demo ! xD) */
        $rows.show();
        $filteredRows.hide();
        /* Prepend no-result row if all rows are filtered */
        if ($filteredRows.length === $rows.length) {
            $table.find('tbody').prepend($('<tr class="no-result text-center"><td colspan="'+ $table.find('.filters th').length +'">No result found</td></tr>'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***filter methods return a new array***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var filter_data = grid.dataSource.filter(item =>
    (
        item.field == field && item.opertor && operator && item.value == value)
    );

console.log(".......filter_data......", filter_data)
```

now you can use this new filter_data

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
_this = this;
// Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
$.each($("#turnoverTaxTbl tbody tr"), function() {
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
       $(this).hide();
    else
       $(this).show();                
});});
```

Comment: maybe this will help you to search in the table.